# Transposing group of data in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe like this:

```
|type| qt  | vol|
|----|---- | -- |
| A  | 1   | 10 |
| A  | 2   | 12 |
| A  | 1   | 12 |
| B  | 3   | 11 |
| B  | 4   | 20 |
| B  | 4   | 20 |
| C  | 4   | 20 |
| C  | 4   | 20 |
| C  | 4   | 20 |
| C  | 4   | 20 |
```

How can I transpose to the dataframe with grouping horizontally like that?

```
|A.            |B.            |C.            |
|--------------|--------------|--------------|
|type| qt | vol|type| qt | vol|type| qt | vol|
|----|----| ---|----|----| ---|----|----| ---|
| A  | 1  | 10 | B  | 3  | 11 | C  | 4  | 20 |
| A  | 2  | 12 | B  | 4  | 20 | C  | 4  | 20 |
| A  | 1  | 12 | B  | 4  | 20 | C  | 4  | 20 |
                              | C  | 4  | 20 |
```

Answer (score 6):

You can `group` the dataframe on `type` then create key-value pairs of groups inside a dict comprehension, finally use `concat` along `axis=1` and pass the optional `keys` parameter to get the final result:

```
d = {k:g.reset_index(drop=True) for k, g in df.groupby('type')}
pd.concat(d.values(), keys=d.keys(), axis=1)
```

Alternatively you can use `groupby` + `cumcount` to create a sequential counter per group, then create a `multilevel` index having two levels where the first level is counter and second level is column `type` itself, finally use  `stack` followed by `unstack` to `reshape`:

```
c = df.groupby('type').cumcount()
df.set_index([c, df['type'].values]).stack().unstack([1, 2])
```

---

```
     A              B              C       
  type   qt  vol type   qt  vol type qt vol
0    A    1   10    B    3   11    C  4  20
1    A    2   12    B    4   20    C  4  20
2    A    1   12    B    4   20    C  4  20
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    C  4  20
```

Comment: Nice... I like the fact that you can use set_index with df['type'] to add a copy of a column to the index and just move the column into the index. +1.  You don't need to add `.values`.

Comment: nice I tried `df.set_index([df.groupby('type').cumcount(),df['type']]).unstack(-1).swaplevel(1,0,axis=1)` but the multi index isn't set properly.

Comment: @Manakin `df.set_index([df['type'].values, df.groupby('type').cumcount()]).unstack(0).swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(level=0, axis=1)` works, although Shubnam has the better solution.

Comment: agreed, very nice as always, treat your self to an idly on me ;)

Comment: Thanks @ScottBoston for your valuable suggestion. I simply used `df['Type'].values` here in order to avoid renaming the index later :)

Comment: Thanks @Manakin happy holidays :)

Comment: @ShubhamSharma I understand and like your reasoning here.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty much pivot by one column:

```
(df.assign(idx=df.groupby('type').cumcount())
   .pivot(index='idx',columns='type', values=df.columns)
   .swaplevel(0,1, axis=1)
   .sort_index(axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
type    A              B            C         
       qt type  vol   qt type  vol qt type vol
idx                                           
0       1    A   10    3    B   11  4    C  20
1       2    A   12    4    B   20  4    C  20
2       1    A   12    4    B   20  4    C  20
3     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  4    C  20
```